# How to convert Vector of Box to Vector of reference?

Tags: vector, rust, reference, boxing

I'm looking for a way to conver `Vec<Box<u32>>` to `Vec<&u32>`. Here is what I tried:

```
fn conver_to_ref(){
    let test: Vec<Box<u32>> = vec![Box::new(1), Box::new(2)];
    let _test2: Vec<&u32> = test.into_iter().map(|elem| &*elem).collect();
}
```

Unfortunately it does not compile: [demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5a74d1a04b296349acbb98a83b4268e). The error message:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to local data `*elem`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:57
  |
3 |     let _test2: Vec<&u32> = test.into_iter().map(|elem| &*elem).collect();
  |                                                         ^^^^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

How to do such conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`into_iter()` consumes the original vector and its items. If the code compiled as written, all the references in `_test2` would be dangling because the boxes would be destroyed along with `test`.

You *can* build a vector of references, but you will need to not consume the original `test` vector, so that the boxes retain an owner. You can simply use `iter()` instead of `into_iter()`:

```
fn convert_to_ref() {
    let test: Vec<Box<u32>> = vec![Box::new(1), Box::new(2)];
    let _test2: Vec<&u32> = test.iter().map(Box::as_ref).collect();
}
```

Note that `test.iter()` yields references to `test` elements, i.e. to the boxes themselves (`&Box<u32>`), and not to the boxed items (`&u32`) which we're interested in. This is why we must apply `as_ref` to get the latter.

Comment: Also `elem.to_ref()` which is nicer than `&**`.

Comment: @Thomas It's `as_ref()`, but yes, much nicer. Amended the answer.

Comment: @SomeName The error message is one of those that is clear once you know what's going on. `into_iter()` destroys the vector and transfer ownership of its items into the iterator, which in turn transfers them to its users, including adapters like `map()`. So when the compiler complains that `elem` is "owned by the current function", the function refers to the closure. Returning a reference to a locally owned value, even though it's boxed, would immediately create a dangling reference, as the box would be destroyed on return from the closure.